# ReactPHP - Keep online on server like "pm2" with "NodeJS" - process manager

Tags: php, node.js, pm2, reactphp

I have been studying "ReactPHP", but I did not understand how to keep it running on the server if there is an error.
I searched and found that "NodeJS" has "pm2" for keep online on the server or if there is an error it restarts, I would like to know if there is a program like PM2 for "ReactPHP"? and how to implement it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just start multiple processes with `SO_REUSEPORT` and have a generic process manager like SupervisorD handle the restarting of crashing processes.